# Structured binding on const

Tags: c++, c++17, structured-bindings

Is the following code supposed to compile?

```
#include <type_traits>

void foo() {
  const std::pair<int, int> x = {1, 2};

  auto [a, b] = x;

  static_assert(std::is_const_v<decltype(a)>);
  static_assert(std::is_const_v<decltype(b)>);
}
```

- [MSVC](https://godbolt.org/z/LCh8Yl) says "yes!".
- [GCC](https://godbolt.org/z/Wlip8O) says "oh no, man!".
- [Clang](https://godbolt.org/z/ggHt0h) says "no way!".

---

So, is this an *MSVC* bug?

The standard is not straightforward here (I had a quick look), but considering the rules for `auto`, I suppose, `a` and `b` should be copied discarding *cv-qualifier*.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

> Is the following code supposed to compile?

It is not. This is an MSVC bug.

[A structured binding declaration](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.struct.bind#1) introduces a new name (for specification only), `e`, that is declared like:

```
auto e = x;
```

The type of `e` is called `E`, and since the initializer is tuple-like, the types of the bindings are given by [`tuple_element_t<i, E>`](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.struct.bind#4). In this case `E` is `pair<int, int>`, so the two types are just `int`. The rule for `decltype` of a structured binding is to give the [referenced type](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.type#decltype-1.1), so `decltype(a)` and `decltype(b)` are both `int`.

The important part here is that `a` and `b` (the structured bindings) come from the invented variable (`e`), and *not* its initializer (`x`). `e` is not `const` because you just declared it `auto`. What we're doing is copying `x`, and then taking bindings into this (non-`const`) copy.

Answer (score 9):

The static assertions in your code *should* fail. Why? Because your code is basically the same as the case of:

```
#include <type_traits>

void foo() {
  const int x_1 = 1;
  const int x_2 = 2;

  auto a = x_1;
  auto b = x_2;

  static_assert(std::is_const_v<decltype(a)>);
  static_assert(std::is_const_v<decltype(b)>);
}
```

which [does indeed fail on MSVC](https://godbolt.org/z/M9zent) as well.

**In C++, expression types decay on assignment**: the `auto` sees an `int`, not a `const int`. Structured binding simply lets you do more than a single `auto` binding at a time.

... and so the fact that MSVC doesn't fail on the assertions in your code seems to be a bug.